# PowerQuery remove items from a list matching a pattern

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

Using PowerQuery in excel how can I remove items from a list that match a pattern.

I have a column with cells that contain names and numeric id's. I want to be left with just a list of names.

```
LastName, FirstName;#123;#LastName, FirstName;#321;
```

The numbers are all unique. So if I had regex the pattern would be similar to

```
/^\#ddd+$/
```

I can split the cell into a list using ';' as a separator.

```
= Text.Split([Consultant],";")
```

If there was a way to remove every 2nd item until the end that could work too. Unfortunately it seems there is no way to specify patterns to match.

```
List.RemoveItems({1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 5}, {2, 4, 6})
```

This would be awesome however I have to define all the number patterns that exist. So this fails.

```
List.RemoveMatchingItems(Text.Split([Consultant], ";#"), {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9})
```

**Method2**
I split the text into a list as above. This gave me a column of lists. So I expanded the lists in columns to new rows. My plan was to remove alternate rows. However, remove alternate rows requires an end number. I would need an argument to go until there are no more arguments to process.

Comment: Is your string all in one cell?  With repeated lastName, Firstname?

Comment: Some sample input and desired output would make this easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways.
One way is to select every other item with `List.Select`

In your example, these would be the items with an even number position.

```
let 
  x = Text.Split([Column1],";#"),
  y = List.Select(x, each Number.IsEven(List.PositionOf(x, _)))
in 
 y
```

***Edit Nov 2022***
Another method or removing every other would be:

```
=List.Alternate(Text.Split([Column1],";#"),1,1,1)
```